# React Native Maps - new pricing

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-api-3, react-native-maps

Since Google switched their pricing model, and Mobile Native Maps are still unlimited while Javascript SDK maps are limited to 28,000 per month as you can see
[here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/).

Does anyone know which category react-native-maps falls under? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find answer in the documentation of react native maps

> The actual map implementation depends on the platform. On Android, one has to use Google Maps, which in turn requires you to obtain an API key for the **Android SDK**.
>
> On iOS, one can choose between Google Maps or the native Apple Maps implementation.
>
> When using Google Maps on iOS, you need to also register for the **iOS SDK** and include the Google Maps library in your build.

source: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

As you can see in case of Android it uses Google Maps Android SDK, in case of iOS it can use Google Maps iOS SDK. The Google Maps JavaScript API is not used in react native maps. That means at the moment the usage is unlimited and free of charge as per Google Maps Platform [price sheet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/).

I hope it clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: Does it mean its unlimited for both business and personal? I have an APP that protected by username and password. Our clients are using the app.

Comment: Is it still true in 2023?

Comment: Is this still true for 2023?

Comment: Yes this is still true https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#mobile-dynamic